# Windows 7/8 and Ubuntu triple boot

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7, windows-8, dual-boot

I already have windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed. Now I want to install windows 8 for a triple boot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure it will not go beyond the **4 primary partitions**; if so then your PC will not boot up.
2. You can make extra partition with GParted--up to four primary partitions, or up to three primary partitions plus an extended partition that acts as a contained for logical partitions. This way you can effectively have more than four partitions.
3. Make sure you have sufficient space for Windows 8.
4. Install Windows 8.
5. Now you notice that only Windows 7 and 8 are listed in Windows's boot loader.
6. You have 2 option to make it so you can select Ubuntu when booting your machine:

   1. Add Ubuntu in windows boot loader by using [easyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
   2. Reinstall GRUB 2 by live CD.

      For this watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I).

      After this if your windows in not listed in grub 2 then type

      ```
      sudo update-grub2
      ```

      Even if Windows is not listed retry after mounting your windows drive.

      Here is [a video for updating GRUB2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDcyAncmRY).

Answer (score 0):

1. Via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted), reduce some partitions in order to make free space on disk
2. Install Windows8 in this free space
3. reinstall GRUB (eg via [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair))

Comment: have you tried it yourself? I just want to know that it works for sure before I mess with my system

Comment: Yes, i did. First i recommend you create a backup image of your disk via CloneZilla, so that you can revert the changes if necessary.

Comment: do you have this problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/141640/windows-7-does-not-boot-correctly-on-a-triple-boot-system-with-windows-8consume?rq=1